# Changing the shape of an image to match dimensions of input shape of model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I trained a model that expects an input shape of `(None, 9, 100, 100, 3)`. When I run the following code:

```
                    start_frame = 1
                    while success:
                       vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)
                       success, image = vid.read()

                       image = np.array(image).astype('float32')/255
                       image = image.reshape(1,*image.shape)
                       image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
                       preds = model.predict(image)
```

I get the following warning/error: `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 9, 100, 100, 3) for input Tensor("conv3d_1_input:0", shape=(None, 9, 100, 100, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (1, 1, 100, 100, 3).`

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `model.predict()` is expecting an array with shape `(1,9,100,100)`

Comment: @rzaratx: So how do you change it?

Comment: @ollie_indy, make sure that the inputs given to the model have a shape of `( None, 9 , 100 , 100 , 3 )`. If you want to repeat the elements ( 8 more times ) to have a shape of `( None, 9 , 100 , 100 , 3 )` from `( None, 1 , 100 , 100 , 3 )`, use [np.repeat()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)